# Override Vuetify SASS variables

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

**Should I import the minified .css file when trying to override SASS variables ?**

I followed this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

And now I'm trying to override `$body-font-family` with no success, I've tried creating a variables.scss file and also tried overriding it in my main .scss file but I wonder if I should be importing the minified version like that or if I need to do something different ?

Answer (score 0):

To override vuetify variables, just create a directory inside your `src` named `scss` and in there create a file called `variables.scss`

Inside that file you can change variables without importing anything.

For example my `variables.scss`

```
$container-max-widths: (
  md: 100%,
  lg: 1200px,
  xl: 1200px
);

$btn-text-transform: none;

$dialog-card-subtitle-padding: 0 56px 20px;
$dialog-card-title-padding: 36px 56px 10px;
$dialog-card-actions-padding: 8px 56px 36px;
$dialog-card-text-padding:0 56px 20px;
```

Comment: I have tried that already but it's not working for me, I'm using vuetify within a webpack project that was originally using a different UI library. I am importing the min css as the link I posted in the question says but really I'm wondering if I shouldn't import that file when overriding SASS variables and what should I import instead.

Comment: There should be no need to import vuetify's main.scss file. I'm only importing `import Vuetify from "vuetify";`

Comment: @code4jhon Did you manage to solve the problem with overwriting variables? I also have a variables.scss file in /src/scss, but I can't overwrite it with e.g. $font-size-root variable.